# lubridate::as_datetime() fails when as.POSIXct() works?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Could someone explain why `lubridate::as_datetime()` fails here, but `as.POSIXct()` works?

```
> as.POSIXct("2020-10-27 20:25")
[1] "2020-10-27 20:25:00 CDT"

> lubridate::as_datetime("2020-10-27 20:25")
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Comment: `as_datetime("2020-10-27 20:25:00")` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the one works and not the other I don't know, but you can help as_datetime() understand the input by suppling a format string, which specifies the format the text string.

```
lubridate::as_datetime("2020-10-27 20:25", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Check out the documentation for as_datetime() and strptime() on how to write the format-string.

edit: It seems that the format argument defaults to NULL for as_datetime, a similar error is generated by as.Posixct() if format = NULL is supplied.

```
as.POSIXct("2020-10-27 20:25", format = NULL)
```